# Basic properties of symmetric difference in sets: $A \Delta B=A \Delta D$ implies $B=D$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I prove that for any sets $A,B,C,D$
if 
$$A \Delta B = C  $$
and
$$A \Delta D = C  $$
then $B=D$.
Where $\Delta$ denotes symmetric difference.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed it up with something else.

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537172/a-oplus-b-a-oplus-c-imply-b-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First show that $\Delta$ is associative and has inverses; namely, every set is its own inverse. Then apply $A$ from the left to both equations and use what you proved in the first step. In doing this, it may help to think of the symmetric difference as XOR.

Answer (score 7):

The probabilist in me cannot resist mentioning that symmetric differences can (and maybe they should) be approached through *indicator functions modulo 2*.

Recall that, for every $A\subseteq E$, the indicator function $\mathbf 1_A$ is defined on $E$ by $\mathbf 1_A(x)=1$ if $x$ is in $A$ and $\mathbf 1_A(x)=0$ if $x$ is in $E\setminus A$.

Then, for every subsets $A$ and $B$ of $E$, the set $C=A\Delta B$ is *uniquely characterized* by the fact that $\mathbf 1_C=\mathbf 1_A+\mathbf 1_B\pmod{2}$ (can you check this?).

A host of properties of $\Delta$ become obvious with this approach since $\Delta$ is simply the sum in the group $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. For example, your hypothesis is that $\mathbf 1_A+\mathbf 1_B=\mathbf 1_C=\mathbf 1_A+\mathbf 1_D\pmod{2}$ hence $\mathbf 1_B=\mathbf 1_D\pmod{2}$. And this is enough to guarantee that $B=D$ (can you check this?).

Note equivalently that, in every group $(G,\ast)$, the identity $g\ast h_1=g\ast h_2$ for some $g$, $h_1$ and $h_2$ in $G$ implies that $g^{-1}\ast g\ast h_1=g^{-1}\ast g\ast h_2$ hence $h_1=h_2$. Homework: what is $g^{-1}$ in the setting of the exercise?

Comment: Seems an expansion of @joriki's suggestion to see $\triangle$ as XOR.

Answer (score 3):

$$B=\emptyset\Delta B=(A\Delta A)\Delta B=A\Delta(A\Delta B)=A\Delta C=A\Delta(A\Delta D)=(A\Delta A)\Delta D=\emptyset\Delta D=D$$

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x$ is in $B$, and deduce from the given equations that it must also be in $D$. Then assume it's in $D$, and deduce by symmetry that it's in $B$. That will prove $B=D$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $b\in B$:

1.: $b\notin A$. This means that $b\in C\setminus A=D\setminus A$ and hence in $D$.

2.: $b\in A$. This means that $b\in A\setminus C=A\cap D$ and hence in $D$.

This proves that $B\subseteq D$ and for the other inclusion just swap $B$ and $D$.

Comment: How do you know that $C\setminus A = D\setminus A$ ?

Comment: @Sunny88: $A\Delta D= C$ are the elements that are either in $A$ or $D$ but not in both. So if $c\in A\Delta D$ but not in $A$ it must be in $D$ (and still not in $A$, so it's in $D\setminus A$).

Answer (score 0):

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \text{"#2"} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
$As a first simplification, we can take out $\;C\;$ and rephrase your theorem as
$$
\tag{0} A \Delta B = A \Delta D \;\Rightarrow\; B = D
$$

The proof depends on your definition and the laws of logic that are available.

In my favorite setting the proof would go something like this:

$$\calc
A \Delta B = A \Delta D
\calcop{\equiv}{set extensionality; definition (1) of $\;\Delta\;$, below, twice}
\langle \forall x :: x \in A \not\equiv x \in B \;\equiv\; x \in A \not\equiv x \in D \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: $\;\equiv\;$ is symmetric}
\langle \forall x :: x \in A \not\equiv x \in A \;\equiv\; x \in B \not\equiv x \in D \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: $\;\not\equiv\;$ is anti-reflexive}
\langle \forall x :: \text{false} \;\equiv\; x \in B \not\equiv x \in D \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: the negation of $\;\not\equiv\;$ is $\;\equiv\;$}
\langle \forall x :: x \in B \equiv x \in D \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{set extensionality}
B = D
\endcalc$$

This completes the proof of (a slightly stronger version of) $(0)$.

Above we used the fact (or alternative definition) that for every $\;x\;$
$$
\tag{1} x \in X \Delta Y \;\equiv\; x \in X \not\equiv x \in Y
$$

Also, we implicitly used the fact that $\;\equiv\;$ and $\;\not\equiv\;$ are not only both associative but also mutually associative.