# $A \oplus B = A \oplus C$ imply $B = C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I don't quite yet understand how $\oplus$ (xor) works yet. I know that fundamentally in terms of truth tables it means only 1 value(p or q) can be true, but not both.
But when it comes to solving problems with them or proving equalities I have no idea how to use $\oplus$.

For example: I'm trying to do a problem in which I have to prove or disprove with a counterexample whether or not $A \oplus B = A \oplus C$  implies $B = C$ is true.

I know that the venn diagram of $\oplus$ in this case includes the regions of A and B excluding the areas they overlap. And similarly it includes regions of A and C but not the areas they overlap. It would look something like this:

[image]

I feel the statement above would be true just by looking at the venn diagram since the area ABC is included in the $\oplus$, but I'm not sure if that's an adequate enough proof. 
On the other hand, I could be completely wrong about my reasoning.

Also just for clarity's sake: Would $A\cup B = A \cup C$ and $A \cap B = A \cap C$ be proven in a similar way to show whether or not the conditions imply $B = C$? A counterexample/ proof of this would be appreciated as well.

Comment: For still more fun show that the power set of a set $X$, together with the xor operation, is a group.  And, of course, groups have the cancellation law you ask about.

Comment: The xor being, in that case, called the symmetric difference. @user101279 : By the way, $\oplus$ is addition modulo $2$.

Comment: Remark also that xor is the addition operation when we regard a Boolean algebra as essentially the same as a Boolean ring.

Comment: Think of $\oplus$ as $\neq$.

Comment: If we omit the question about intersection and union in the last paragraph, this is the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294460/basic-properties-of-symmetric-difference-in-sets-a-delta-b-a-delta-d-implie

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Think of $\oplus$ as $\neq$. That is $A \oplus B$ **iff** $A \neq B$.

Note that $A \oplus A$ is always false, and $\text{False}\oplus A = A$.

Then 
$A \oplus (A \oplus B) = (A \oplus A) \oplus B = \text{False} \oplus B = B $.

Similarly, $A \oplus (A \oplus C) = C$, hence $B=C$.

**Aside**: A 'cute' (as in amusing but not of any practical significance) use of $\oplus$ is to swap the values of two bit variables in a programming language without using an intermediate variable:
\begin{eqnarray}
x = y \oplus x \\
y = y \oplus x \\
x = y \oplus x \\
\end{eqnarray}
Show that the values of $x,y$ are swapped!

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $A\oplus(A\oplus B)=(A\oplus A)\oplus B = B$.

And of course $A\cup B=A\cup C$ does not imply $B=C$ (consider the case $B=A\ne \emptyset = C$). And $A\cap B=A\cap C$ does not imply $B=C$ either (consider the case $A=\emptyset$)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\oplus$ is associative with unit $\emptyset$, and $A \oplus A = \emptyset$. Does this give you an idea for canceling?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a simple calculation.  But I don't know how to interpret your question, so I'll give two answers. :-)

---

I'm assuming $\;A,B,C\;$ are booleans.  I will write $\;\not\equiv\;$ instead of $\;\oplus\;$, and $\;\equiv\;$ instead of $\;=\;$ on booleans.

First, note that $\;\equiv\;$ and $\;\not\equiv\;$ are not only both associative, but they are also mutually associative.  Therefore no parentheses are needed in the following calculation.

We can now simplify $\;A \oplus B = A \oplus C\;$ as follows:
\begin{align}
& A \not\equiv B \equiv A \not\equiv C \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"rearrange"} \\
& A \not\equiv A \equiv B \not\equiv C \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"simplify"} \\
& \text{false} \equiv B \not\equiv C \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"simplify"} \\
& B \equiv C \\
\end{align}

---

If instead $\;A,B,C\;$ are sets, and your $\;\oplus\;$ is the symmetric difference of two sets (which is normally written as $\;\triangle\;$), then the proof is slightly longer, but with essentially the same structure.

The simplest definition of symmetric difference is
$$
x \in A \oplus B \equiv x \in A \not\equiv x \in B
$$

We can expand the definitions and simplify using logic, as follows:
\begin{align}
& A \oplus B = A \oplus C \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"set extensionality; definition of $\;\oplus\;$, twice"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \not\equiv x \in B \equiv x \in A \not\equiv x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: rearrange"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \not\equiv x \in A \equiv x \in B \not\equiv x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: simplify"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: \text{false} \equiv x \in B \not\equiv x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: simplify"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in B \equiv x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"set extensionality"} \\
& B = C \\
\end{align}

---

In both cases, we have found a stronger conclusion than was asked: we proved equivalence of the two expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You asked this additional question in the last paragraph:

> Also just for clarity's sake: Would $A\cup B = A \cup C$ and $A \cap B = A \cap C$ be proven in a similar way to show whether or not the conditions imply $B = C$? A counterexample/ proof of this would be appreciated as well.

---

$A\cup B=A\cup C$ $\Rightarrow$ $B=C$ is not true in general.

Counterexample: Take any non-empty set $A$ and also take $B=A$ and $C=\emptyset$. Then $A\cup B=A\cup C=A$, but $B\ne C$.

---

$A\cap B=A\cap C$ $\Rightarrow$ $B=C$ is not true in general.

Take some element $x\notin A$ and put $B=A$, $C=A\cup\{x\}$. Then $A\cap B=A\cap C=A$, but $B\ne C$.