# Property of symmetric set difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $A \Delta B$ represent the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$ (i.e. $A \Delta B = (A \cap \bar{B}) \cup (\bar{A} \cap B)$). The following property of $\Delta$ is known: If $A \Delta B = A \Delta C$, then $B = C$. Now, I would like to prove this property only with the aid of the known properties of $\cap$ and $\cup$ (associativity, commutativity, etc.). In other words, I don't want to use the definitions of $\cap$ and $\cup$. I don't want the proof to say something like "Let $x \in A \Delta B \ldots$" etc. Is that possible? I have tried, but I can't find the way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$A \oplus B = A \oplus C$ imply $B = C$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537172/a-oplus-b-a-oplus-c-imply-b-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$B=\emptyset\mathbin\triangle B=(A\mathbin\triangle A)\mathbin\triangle B=A\mathbin\triangle(A\mathbin\triangle B)=A\mathbin\triangle(A\mathbin\triangle C)=(A\mathbin\triangle A)\mathbin\triangle C=\emptyset\mathbin\triangle C=C$$

Comment: Thanks. It's not trivial either to prove the associativity of $\Delta$, but this will certainly do.

Comment: @ManolitoPérez An element is in a composed set difference iff it occurs in an odd number of the sets (counting repeated occurrences), which is independent of the order of association, and that's reasonably elementary, no?

Comment: Well, I don't see that, sorry :-). I proved the associativity of $\Delta$ in the straightforward way, i.e. by replacing $A \Delta B$ by $(A \cap \bar{B}) \cup (\bar{A} \cap B)$, and then using the properties of $\cup$ and $\cap$. It's a bit long, but straightforward.