# If $A∆B=A∆C$, then $B=C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A\Delta B=A\Delta C$, then $B=C$.

I use the formula  $X∆Y=(X\setminus Y)\cup(Y\setminus X)$ in $A∆B=A∆C$. And further use the formula $X\setminus Y=X\cap Y^c$. I am not  able to reach the conclusion. Please help me.

Comment: Note $X\triangle(X\triangle Y)=Y$.

Comment: When in doubt, do element but element.  If $x \in B$ and $x \in A\Delta B$ then $x \not \in A\setminus B$ so $x \in B\setminus A$ so $x \not \in A$.  So $x \not \in A\setminus C$.  But $x \in A\Delta C = A\Delta B$ so $x \in C\setminus A$ and $x \in C$.  If $x \not \in A\Delta B$ then$x \in A$ and $x \not \in A \Delta C$ so $x \not \in A\setminus C$ so $x \in C$.  So either way $x \in C$ and $B \subset C$.  etc.

Comment: Interesting bit of MathJax lore: $$\begin{align}
& \quad ∆C \\
& \quad\mathbin{\Delta} C \\
& A\mathbin{\Delta} C \\
& A∆C \\
& A \Delta C
\end{align}$$ The use of ∆ rather than \Delta in MathJax code causes it to appear as if it had said \mathbin{\Delta} except when nothing precedes it, in which case the spacing is as if it had had something before it. Three of the posted answers use a capital $\Delta$ and all three of them neglect this.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537172/a-oplus-b-a-oplus-c-imply-b-c) and other posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/537172).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways: know or prove that $. \Delta .$ is a self-inverse group operation:

$$B = \emptyset \Delta B = (A \Delta A) \Delta B = A \Delta (A \Delta B) = A \Delta (A \Delta C) = (A \Delta A) \Delta C = \emptyset \Delta C = C$$

Or a direct proof using inclusion and the definitions:

Suppose $A \Delta B ( = (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) )= A \Delta C$.

Let $x \in B$. If $x \notin A$ then $x \in A \Delta B$ so $x \in A \Delta C$ and as $x \notin A$ we get $x \in C$.

If $x \in A$. the $x \notin A \Delta B$ so $x \notin A \Delta C$, and as $x \in A$ this means that $x \in C$ as well.

So $B \subseteq C$. The other inclusion is the same, interchanging  the rôles of $B$ and $C$.

Answer (score 2):

The key to such problems is to follow a single, arbitrary, element through the equations.

I will prove $B\subseteq C$.  Let $b\in B$ be arbitrary.  We now have two cases.  If $b\in A$, then $b\notin A\Delta B$.  Since $A\Delta B=A\Delta C$, then $b\notin A\Delta C$.  But $b\in A$, so we must have $b\in C$.  The second case is if $b\notin A$.  Now $b\in A\Delta B = A\Delta C$.  Since $b\notin A$, we must have $b\in C$.  So, in both cases, for any $b\in B$, we must have $b\in C$.  This proves $B\subseteq C$.

We now do a similar argument (or use symmetry) to prove that $C\subseteq B$.  Combining with the previous we conclude that $B=C$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the indicator functions in $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$: consider $X := A\cup B\cup C$ so that for $D\subset X$, $\Bbb{1}_D: X \to \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ is defined as usual. Then $\Bbb{1}_{D\Delta E}= \Bbb{1}_D + \Bbb{1}_E$ for all $D,E\subset X$ (simple calculation).

Thus $A\Delta B = A\Delta C \iff \Bbb{1}_{A\Delta B} = \Bbb{1}_{A\Delta C} \iff \Bbb{1}_A + \Bbb{1}_B = \Bbb{1}_A + \Bbb{1}_C \iff \Bbb{1}_B =\Bbb{1}_C \iff B=C$

Comment: That's really clever!

Answer (score 1):

Since $A\setminus B\cup A\setminus C=A\setminus B\cap C$ and $B\setminus A \cup C\setminus A= B\cup C\setminus A$
$$A\Delta B\cup A\Delta C=(A\cup B\cup C)\setminus (A\cap B\cap C)$$.

But since $A\Delta B\cup A\Delta C=A\Delta B$, $C\setminus A\Delta B=(A\cap B\cap C)$

Similarly since $A\Delta B\cup A\Delta C=A\Delta C$, $B\setminus A\Delta C=(A\cap B\cap C)=B\setminus A\Delta B$.

Then $C\setminus A\Delta B=B\setminus A\Delta B$. Hence $B=C\space\space\space\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

You can do element chasing.

Or you can manipulate symbols and properties and identities.

But you can also divide and conquer.

Divide the space into $8$ disjoint sets determined by the elements that are are not in $A,B,C$.

They are:

1) $A^c \cap B^c \cap C^c$ (the elements that are in none)

2)  $A^c \cap B^c \cap C$

3)  $A^c \cap B \cap C^c$

4)  $A^c \cap B \cap C$

5)  $A \cap B^c \cap C^c$

6) $A \cap B^c \cap C$

7) $A \cap B \cap C^c$

8) $A \cap B \cap C$

$A\Delta B$ consists of $3$ and $4$ and $5$ and $6$  but none of the others $1,2,7,8$.

$A \Delta C$ consists of $2$ and $4$ and $5$ and $7$ but none of the others $1,3,6,8$.

So we get the seemingly paradoxical result that sets $2,3,6,7$ are all both subsets of $A \Delta B = A \Delta C$, and completely disjoint from $A \Delta B = A \Delta C$.  The only way a set can be both a subset and disjoint from another set, is if the set is empty.  So $2,3,6,7$ are all empty.

$B = 3 \cup 4\cup 7 \cup 8 = 4 \cup 8$.

$C = 2 \cup 4 \cup 6 \cup 8 = 4 \cup 8 = B$.